# Mock a class's constant and method with Mockery and PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

Newbie to Mockery... I am testing one class (Buzz in my oversimplified bland example) that invokes a method from another class(Foo->getData), and I have a mock that mocks this method which works great. Now I added checking against a class constant(Foo::FIZZ) and my test breaks due to the constant not defined.

I've tried to add the constant by mapping the constant as shown in the [Mockery Docs here](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/class_constants.html#constants-map), but it's still saying constant FOO\Bar::FIZZ not defined. I haven't been able to find any other way to set the constants to my Mockery mock. Any help would be appreciated!

Constraint: I have to use the overload Mockery due to some [hard dependencies](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html) inside the mocked class.

```
namespace Foo; 

class Bar() {
  const FIZZ = 'hello';

  public function getData() {
    //retrieve $data from database
    return $data;
  }
}

class Buzz() {

  public function returnResult() {
    $result = Foo\Bar->getData();
    if ($result !== Foo\Bar::FIZZ) { // if result is different than my constant, return it
      return $result;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and in my test:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Mockery;
use Foo;

class BuzzTest extends TestCase {

   \Mockery::getConfiguration()->setConstantsMap([
    'Bar' => [
        'FIZZ' => 'hello',
    ]
  ]);

  public function testBuzzRejectsIfEqual(): void {

        $externalMock = \Mockery::mock('overload:\Foo\Bar')
            ->shouldReceive('getData')
            ->andReturn('hello');

        $obj = new \Foo\Buzz();
        $actual = $obj->returnResult();
        $this->assertEquals($actual, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this awesome article https://blog.gougousis.net/mocking-static-methods-with-mockery/ I was able to finally make this work using named mocks.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Mockery;
use Foo;

class BuzzTest extends TestCase {


  public function testBuzzRejectsIfEqual(): void {

        $externalMock = \Mockery::namedMock(Foo\Bar:class, BarStub::class)
            ->shouldReceive('getData')
            ->andReturn('hello');

        $obj = new \Foo\Buzz();
        $actual = $obj->returnResult();
        $this->assertEquals($actual, false);
  }
}

class BarStub {
  const FIZZ = 'hello';
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)